# What file descriptor am I supposed to close using pipe and dup2

Tags: c, pipe, dup2

Sample code without error handling

```
int pipes[2];

pipe(pipes);
int pid = fork();

if (pid == CHILD)
{
   close(pipes[0]); //close useless read fd
   dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, pipes[1]); //replace default output by writer piped fd
   execve(...);
   close(pipes[1]); // ??????????
}
else //parent
{
  close(pipes[1]); //close useless write fd
  dup2(STDIN_FILENO, pipes[0]); //replace default input by reader piped fd
  read(pipes[0]..);
  close(pipes[0]);
}
```

In the child, we know that a default output/input is automatically closed at the end of the program (STDIN_FILENO/STDOUT_FILENO).
If I use `dup2()` to change the default input/output, will my pipes[1] be closed automatically? Or Have I to do it myself and then how? I'm thinking that `execve` stops my program on its line on success.

Comment: `execve` doesn't return. The current process will have been replaced by the new executable.

Comment: ye I know it, it's not my problem

Comment: Closing a process also closes all file descriptors that that process had open. So yes, `pipes[1]` will be closed in the child process once it terminates.

Comment: @Romain, ...and to contradict: What the first comment describes **is** your problem, because the `close` doesn't run at all unless you put it **before** the `execve()`. Consequently, your processes inherit two different copies of their stdin or stdout -- one on FD 0 or 1, and the other on the FIFO descriptor.

Comment: Actually, each process inherits a copy of **both** sides of the FIFO, which is even worse: The reader will never detect its stdin as closed, because *it itself* is holding the write side of the pipeline open.

Comment: **Rule of thumb**: if you duplicate one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, you should close *both* ends of the original pipe before using `exec*()` functions (or otherwise continuing).  There are exceptions; they are few and far between.  It is very seldom (on SO, and IRL) that you encounter a program using pipes that closes too many descriptors; it is very common to find a program that doesn't close enough descriptors.  It's especially common if there are multiple children and multiple pipes to confuse things.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler interessting. In my case, Im working on a shell and I have to handle multiple pipes. How should I close the descriptor, knowing that I can't close it before execve() (because I need to redirect the output to my pipe[1])

Comment: You can and should close it before the `execve()` because that process is not going to do anything more with it — the replacement process won't know about the extra opened file descriptor.  You need to distinguish between the parent process and the child process.  The child process can't close the descriptors in the parent any more than the parent can close the descriptors in the child.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ In the fragment in the question, the parent is going to read the child's pipe.  The `dup2(STDIN_FILENO, pipes[0])` is wrong; it closes the pipe file descriptor in `pipes[0]` and makes that descriptor refer to the same file as standard input.  You should simply drop the `dup2()` in the parent; it isn't what you want.  The rest then makes sense — the parent can read from the read end of the pipe. You need to capture the return value from `read()`; the data will not usually be null terminated (it won't be null terminated unless the writing (child) process writes the null byte.)